# ELAN0504:01 04F3:309E Touchpad Multitouch

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

When running in Windows, I'm able to use multitouch gestures with my touchpad.  Unfortunately, when running on Ubuntu 19.10, I can't do a two-finger back gesture in my browser or any three or four finger gestures.

The device appears to be detecting fine and again -- multitouch works in Windows.  What would I need to do to get it working the same under Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try fusuma. https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma

Two-finger swipe is not available, but three-finger and four-finger swipes are implemented.